# Python how do I print 2D grid elements without nested loops?

Tags: python, grid, 2d, valueerror

new python learner here.
I tried to print each element in my 2D grid by using 2 variables in my loop instead of nested loop, here is the code:

```
number_grid = [
[1, 2, 3],
[4, 5, 6],
[7, 8, 9],
[0]
]

for r, c in number_grid:
print(r, c)
```

and I get this error :

```
 for r, c in number_grid:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am also interested in understanding the meaning and the reason as to why I get this error message. Thank you.

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: 1 2 3 up to 9 0

Comment: I am also interested in understanding the meaning of this error.

Comment: The first item in number_grid has 3 items, but you are only unpacking two of them in ```for r, c in number_grid```. You are also going to encounter an error in the last element, which only has 1 item.

Comment: your rows has 3 items but you assign it two variables - `r, c` - so it doesn't know what to do with third element. You have to assign to three variables - ie. `item1, item2, item3` - or assign to one variable - ie `row` and later use `row[0]`, `row[1]`, `row[2]`.

Comment: you can't use single `for` for nested data.

Comment: @furas thank you that was the most helpful answer, I get it now.

Answer (score 2):

By calling `for r,c in number_grid`, you are unpacking the inner list as you iterate over the outer list. The problem is that the first inner list [1, 2, 3] has 3 elements, and you are trying to unpack it into only two variables, r and c. You will also get an error in the final inner_list [0], which only has 1 element, thus leaving nothing to unpack into c.

You might have more success by iterating over the outer list. A starting point would be something like the code below, where each `row` is a list that you can print or modify appropriately.

```
for row in number_grid: 
    print(' '.join([str(item) for item in row]))
```

Comment: Alternative: Flatten the list and print them. You can use `itertools.chain(*iterable)` or `itertools.chain.from_iterable(iterable)` to flatten or list comp to flatten `[i for slst in lst for i in slst]`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a nice explanation [here](https://www.stechies.com/valueerror-too-many-values-unpack-python/) on why you get that error and how to solve this.

To print numbers without nested loops, you can use the following ways:

```
number_grid = [[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9],
               [0]]

for grid in number_grid:
    print(*grid)

# 1 2 3
# 4 5 6
# 7 8 9
# 0
```

Or:

```
number_grid = [[1, 2, 3],
               [4, 5, 6],
               [7, 8, 9],
               [0]]

print(' '.join(map(str, list(itertools.chain(*number_grid)))))

# 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
```